# LessCss extend broken when using parent selector

Tags: less

I am using &:extend(.klass)

I have a method:

```
.method(@mixin) {

      html[something] & { @mixin() }

}

.klass {

      .method({});

}
```

So far so good. However, when I use this:

```
.anotherclass { &:extend(.klass)  }
```

I get no complaints, it extends the klass properly.

Resulting css:

```
html[something] .klass  { ... } 
.klass, .anotherclass { ... }
```

However, it should ideally, also extend the html[something] .klass as well.

So the result should **IDEALLY** be:

```
html[something] .klass, html[something] .anotherclass  { ... } 
.klass, .anotherclass { ... }
```

Right?

Otherwise, you could end up using &:extend(.klass) get no complaint, expecting to get the right rules applied.

I am using **less on java**, and it might be using an old version.

Does this work "better" in newer versions?

Note, I am aware I can just turn klass into a method call instead.

Comment: It might be a problem with the *minimal* code posted but the code posted here won't compile because `.method()` won't match the selector above and needs a parameter to be provided. But that said adding `&:extend(.klass all);` (with the `all` keyword) should produce the desired output in latest versions of compiler.

Comment: Thanks Harry, that did work! However, I think this should be the default. I actually already knew about all but had forgotten about it. Imagine you have a bunch of developers who you know need to communicate to always use all everywhere ( that's the safe thing to do and the intuitive thing considering everything else gives you the desired behaviour ). I understand backward compatibility might be problem now, but you could introduce a new separate keyword, inherit or similar.

Comment: I am not part of the Less core development team mate. But there are people from the team who frequent Stack Overflow and they would be able to answer that question of yours :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. For whoever reads this, here are another argument i just discovered. If a class extends another class, withouth the use of all, a third class can extend the second one without the use of all and get put at the top level as well. So all is only required for method calls, which is a bit bogus. I will enforce the use of all for now, but there is a distinction between a extend of a class that extends a class and an extend of class that invokes a method ( which uses the parent selector )

Comment: To answer about "`all` should be default", no, there a lot of reasons it should not (technically when other more Less-convenient `extend` keywords are implemented, `all` will/should be used almost never). For more details see [#2101](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2101).